# Returning references from c++ methods

Tags: c++

I have the following function which is supposed to create an object, insert into an array and return a reference to the element.

`Object& add(attr1, attr2,...).`

I am wondering how I can return a null reference when the the array is full.
Is it possible or is the design wrong in this case?

Comment: Reference cannot be "null". Its always bind to something. Pointer would suit your usecase better.

Comment: C++ is not Java, no null references here. If you want to return null values, you can use pointers or `std::optional`, but I'd avoid it if possible.

Comment: As @FilipKočica said, or you can throw an `exception`, the design may be correct for this case either.

Comment: If you can not insert into array because it is full or because object construction failure it would be a good idea to throw an exception, just like `std::vector::push_back` does.

Comment: Is this scenario a user case or an error? Exception would be better is this is an error. If this should be handled as a user case, you should return a pointer since null is a valid scenario.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks, I will investigate either pointer or throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here. C++ is not like Python, Java, or C#. A reference is simply an alias to an existing value. A reference must alias something. It all depends on what you are trying to do.

Here are your options:

1. Return a pointer instead of a reference. This way you can return a nullptr. Be careful not to put it into unique_ptr or shared_ptr, or delete it.
2. Make a special sentinel value of type Object and instantiate it as a static variable somewhere. Return a reference to that instead of null. This is dangerous with non-const references, since someone might change the sentinel object.
3. If this is a rare occasion that indicates a bug or something exceptional, throw an exception. C++ is not Python and exceptions should not be used for common things like StopIteration is used in Python.
4. Use a dynamic container instead of an array. Maybe `std::vector`, or `std::deque`. This way you won't run out of space easily. But this has a danger of invalidating the reference. If you are afraid to invalidate references, maybe use `std::map`, or `unordered_map` to map indexes to objects.
5. Return `std::optional<std::ref<Object>>`. A variable `x` of this type, can be accessed with:

   `auto x = add(.....);
   if (x /* or x.has_value() */) {
           std::cout << x->get() << "\n";
           x->get() = different_value;
   }`

The last three options are the safest.